# Can I use CSS with SVG or I can only use partially?

Tags: html, css, svg

I read somewhere that CSS and SVG don't go together, but CSS clearly works with SVG. Look at this example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
    rect:hover{
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg> 
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:#d64526" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

This works, but if I change the CSS element to this:

```
rect:hover{
 fill: blue;
}
```

Color would NOT change on hover. What is going on? It partially works?

Comment: I suggest watching a [chris coyden primer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lM7cuk5DPgc)

Comment: Not everything you read on the internet is true. CSS and SVG do work together.

Comment: @MatthewRath why your comment is not upvoted more :D ??

Comment: meh probs because it's not a specific answer, though extremely relevant.

Answer (score 4):

> What is going on? It partially works?

The inline style (added via the `style` attribute) is more specific which means that it is overriding the color that is added on hover. Inline styles added to an element will always overwrite any styles in the CSS (unless you use `!important`, which should always be avoided).

See this MDN article on [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

If you set the initial color using the selector `rect`, it would work as expected because `rect:hover` has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `rect` which means that it will be overridden.

```css
rect {
  fill: #d64526
}
rect:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect width="300" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. But then why do some people say you can't use svg with css?

Comment: @DarkNight As you have demonstrated, you can use CSS with SVG, so I'm not sure why they would say that. Was it an old article?

Comment: Yes, will try to find the URL shortly.